# Problem with duplicate table classes with multiple contexts

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I have two databases, Sales and Production.  For a certain set of tables, the schema is exactly the same.  I generated two contexts using the Database First method.  I specified a different namespace for both.

However, the designer doesn't actually wrap the classes in SalesStore.Context.vb in a namespace.  And when I add it manually, of course it gets lost the next time I make a change to the model.

And so I am getting a bunch of errors: 'multiple definitions with identical signatures'.

How can I change the model so that the namespace is attributed properly to the generated table classes?

TIA,

Miles

Comment: UPDATE: I can right-click on the .tt file and specify a Custom Tool Namespace. But that only wraps the context, and not the table class definitions.  How do I get the table classes either generating inside the context namespace, or have each generated file to also have the same Custom Tool Namespace?

Comment: Update 2:  I found that I can add a Custom Tool Namespace to each table.  But in the end, that is still problematic.  Given a scenario where I am essentially comparing the data from two identical schemas, there should only be one definition for a table class.

But that appears to not be possible with EF6.  Each .edmx files encasulates the data definitions within its own context; which in most (all?) other circumstances would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Use [code-first from an existing database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/existing-database) workflow.  This will allow you to stich together the generated models and share entity types between DbContexts.  It's a little bit of work, but once you ditch the EF designer, you'll never miss it.

Comment: Yes, thank you!  This helped a lot.  I some other questions about Code-First, but will address those in a separate thread.